# pdf display Content-Disposition: inline not working in php

Tags: php, html, pdf, zend-framework

want to display pdf in php so i created following code

```
$file = '../public/'.$ref;
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');  

@readfile($file);
```

but browser showing weird contents , like below image
[image]

i changed Content-Disposition in to attachment, its working fine but no luck in inline what i can do to fix this issue thanks in advance

Comment: What do you want exactly ? for example show the content into a div ?

Comment: There are couple things you can do. 
1)
Remove these two lines:
`header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');`
2)Try different browser. Are you sure that your browser can load PDF inline? Does it do for other sites? Ideally, `Content-Disposition: attachment;` is more common, unless you have specific requirement.

Comment: thank you for your reply , i tried what you said , also tried different browser but no luck

Answer (score 0):

finally code is working , i comment following lines in bootstrap.php file

```
 public static function sendResponse(Zend_Controller_Response_Http $response)
{
   //$response->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=iso-8859-1', true);
   $response->sendResponse();
}
```

but i need this charset in my response header , there is any other method?